# Designing login page in bootstrap but background image is not displaying

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="container vertical-center" style="background: url('background.png')";>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">LOGIN</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" />
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="text-center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="align-content: center">Submit</button>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="panel-footer">Trademark</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my code i have written the entire code i dont know why stack
 overflow is displaying like this....
please help me regarding this
[IMAGE IS HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gAOD.jpg)

[SKYRIM BACKGROUND](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYWvu.jpg)

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: i have written the entire code i dont know why stack overflow is displaying like this....

Comment: the background image gets chopped into 20-30 small images and then it is displayed altogether or it displays nothing at all

Comment: can u upload the screenshot of your display?

Comment: done please check now

Comment: So do you want to display background image at full background?

Comment: YES.................

Comment: check my answer, if it works mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

You can try change your first line to

```
<div class="container vertical-center" style="background: url('background.png'); background-repeat: repeat;">
```

Comment: Sry dude but its still a blank white display

Comment: check the size of ur image thats why it gets chopped into small images or if it doesnot display, check the location of image is correct or not?.. can u upload the image that u r using as background.png

Comment: I directly right click the solution and pasted the image there...tried with different image also it displays white background only

Comment: can you upload only this image `background.png`

Comment: i did this <body background="skyrim.jpg"> let it be....that previous code looks like it wont work at all...idk why ..anyway image is added check question...but now its not responsive image..it stays at its original resolution..check skyrim image

Comment: Its because the image size is very small thats why it is repeating.. use a larger image or use a texture image even if it repeats if will look better..

Comment: but why do i have to use this only <body background="skyrim.jpg">  the other code posted is not working at all... now i am using big skyrim image but it stays at original resolution it is not responsive design...

Answer (score 0):

```
html { 
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

this is the code that works properly.
makes background image responsive as well.
found answer on stackoverflow only